# Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).listFiles() returning null from android Q?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to read the list of files in download folders from the user download directory. I am using  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).listFiles() for getting the files from download. But from android Q its returning null. As per the documentation it is deprecated for the user privacy, So how to get the download folder files from the user for the versions which are above Q.!

Comment: Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user choose the Download folder.

Comment: @blackapps. Cant we do it automatically. Like the above method i shared? If not what will be the scenario? We need to trigger an intent ?

Comment: Yes indeed you do.

Comment: @blackapps. Can u post some example how to get the list of download directory by triggering an intent in here, So it might help others too. Thanks

Comment: Others are already helped. Just google for this action to setup the intent.

Comment: @blackapps . Ya that will do. I am successfully getting the uri of the file selected from the user. But how will get the file path from that uri. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You will not get the file path from that uri to begin with.

Comment: so what shall i do to get file path. Ultimately i need a file path for further process. How to get the file path from content uri.  Thanks

Comment: If any one is looking for same qurey, Please check this answer. Thanks                    https://stackoverflow.com/a/58535155/10534156

Comment: That does not get the file path from the uri either. It just makes a copy to the file system and uses that copy afterwards. Copying the file first has been advised here a hundred times.

Comment: @blackapps. We cannot get the file path from the uri. That's why we need to do like this to get the path. If you know any other way kindly added your answer .

Comment: It looks as if you do not realise that you are making a copy of the file first and then use that copy.

Comment: @blackapps. I realised  . And i understand what iam doing there. But if you are suggesting any other solution, Can you explain it is what iam asking for so long!