# How to get file path from the content uri for zip file?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am triggering an intent for selecting a zip file and in onActivityResult, it is providing me a content URI. For example  :: (content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/197). The file which is selected is from the download folder. Can any one explain, How to query the content resolver in order to get the file path? Thanks.

```
Already tried code :- 

   Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver()
                .query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);

        try {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String path=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                Log.i(TAG, "path  Name: " + path);
            }
           // NOTE :: Here I am getting the file name, But i want the file path.
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
```

Comment: try this https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-get-real-file-path-from-android-uri/

Comment: @Kevin. I tried with the above url. I tested it. and its not working in android Oreo and above version. Especially Iam looking for android Q. Since google suggested Scoped storage . Iam using SAF method to retrieve data . But it is not happening.. Thanks

Comment: The Downloads directory is at `/storage/emulated/0/Downloads`. So if you know the displayName the file path is  `/storage/emulated/0/Downloads/displayName`. But under Android.Q you have no acces there. I wonder what you did with saf to retrieve data. Which data? And what is not happening? And why do you want the file path if it is not reachable under Android.Q ?

Comment: I need to get data from downloaded zip file which is in download directory. In order to open the file and extract it i need a file path. Because of which i need the file path. I am triggering an intent to make the user choose the zip file, after selecting i am receiving content uri . But with that i can get only display name and size while query in content resolver. How to get the downloaded zip file path in android Q is my query @blackapps.  If its not possible in android Q what shall i do to get it. ?

Comment: ??? If it is not possible than you cannot get it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many methods to retrieve the file path from the selected file in download folder. Since from android Q on-wards google suggested SAF(Storage Access Framework) to get the data from the user. We cannot use Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() to get the file path from android Q and above.

For android Q and above you can follow this steps.

1) Start the intent from the activity or fragment you want to trigger.

For example :

```
public void performFileSearch() { //from developer docs

    // ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is the intent to choose a file via the system's file
    // browser.
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

    // Filter to only show results that can be "opened", such as a
    // file (as opposed to a list of contacts or timezones)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    // Filter to show only images, using the image MIME data type.
    // If one wanted to search for ogg vorbis files, the type would be "audio/ogg".
    // To search for all documents available via installed storage providers,
    // it would be "*/*".
    intent.setType("application/pdf"); // MIME type for what file you required

    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

2) Then result will come in onActivityResult of your activity or fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent resultData) { // from developer docs

    // The ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent was sent with the request code
    // READ_REQUEST_CODE. If the request code seen here doesn't match, it's the
    // response to some other intent, and the code below shouldn't run at all.

    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // The document selected by the user won't be returned in the intent.
        // Instead, a URI to that document will be contained in the return intent
        // provided to this method as a parameter.
        // Pull that URI using resultData.getData().
        Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();
            Log.i(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());
            processWithUriToGetPath(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Extracting data from uri(Note: For image,video and audio you can refer developer document.Since didn't find any proper document for file, giving this example).

```
    private void processWithUriToGetPath(Uri contentUri) {
        //Use content Resolver to get the input stream that it holds the data and copy that in a temp file of your app file directory for your references
         File selectedFile = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), "your file name"); //your app file dir or cache dir you can use
       InputStream in = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentUri);
                 OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(selectedFile);
                        try {
                            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                            int len;
                            if (in != null) {
                                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                                }
                                out.close();
                                in.close();
                            } catch (IOException ie) {
                            ie.printStackTrace();
                        }


 //after this you will get file from the selected file and you can do 
           whatever with your wish.
         // Hope it helps... 
    }
```